# Why isn't my toast working? (android)

Tags: java, android, xml, toast

I am trying to figure out why my toast message isn't popping up whenever you push the button.  Whenever you push the button, nothing happens.  I have done some research and can't figure this out.  I am very new to this.  I am a student trying to learn how to become an android developer.  Can anyone help?

This is my java:

```
package com.example.mymusicplaylist;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nation);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    public void nClickHandler(View v) {
        Button nBut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nationButton);
        nBut.isClickable();
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.nationButton:
                if (nBut.isPressed()) {
                    Toast nToast = Toast.makeText(this, "Just imagine listening to the song", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    nToast.show();

                }


        }
    }
}



And here is my xml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.mymusicplaylist.NationActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/nation"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_nation" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="@string/nation"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="62dp"/></LinearLayout>



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nationButton"
        android:onClick="nClickHandler"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:text="Press to Play 7 Nation Army"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Try holding the button for a second or two, see if it pops up then and write a comment (tag me). I'm placing my bets that `if (nBut.isPressed()) {` will be false at the time the code execution reaches this line and therefore it won't make a toast.

Comment: Why using `if (nBut.isPressed())` condition ?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing, makes sense only if he deliberately wanted the toast to show when holding the button :D

Comment: Not working when holding button longer either.  @Vucko

Comment: `wanted the toast to show when holding the button` then use `Button.setOnTouchListener` instead of `Button.OnClickListener`

Comment: I think you should use onTouch event instead of onClick. Agree with @ρяσѕρєяK

Comment: Just remove the `if (nBut.isPressed()) {`, you do not need it. and it'll work.

Comment: I removed it and it's not working.

Comment: Problem fixed.  apparently there wasn't a problem and your guys solutions was working the whole time.   For whatever reason, my app wasnt updating on my phone when I was rerunning it.  So I had to uninstall the app and reinstall it and it was working just fine.  Thx everybody for your help.

Answer (score 1):

nClickHandler is already handling a click event for the button meaning it is already pressed. All you need in that method is to instantiate the toast and show it:

```
public void nClickHandler(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.nationButton:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Just imagine listening to the song", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not right. re-arrange you code like below.

```
public class NationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nation);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Button nBut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nationButton);
        nBut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                nClickHandler();
            }
        });
    }

    public void nClickHandler() {
        Toast nToast = Toast.makeText(this, "Just imagine listening to the song", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        nToast.show();
    }
}
```